# Resizing a UILabel height based on number of lines

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have been following [this tutorial from the Ray Wenderlich site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout#comments) for sizing cells using AutoLayout in iOS 7. (I can't drop iOS 7 support for self sizing cells in iOS 8).

And I'm 99.9% of the way done. The problem I'm having is that if the last line of text is a tiny bit wider than the width of the UILabel then it won't push it to the next line it will truncate the last line.

If I change the `truncate tail` to `clip` then I can see that it's clipping at most a pixel or two from the end.

If the text is longer then it pops to the next line but then when the next line gets just a tiny bit longer than the width of the label it truncates the text again.

All my code is unedited from the code in the tutorial. The sizing cell the height calculation and the UILabel subclass are all identical.

Does anyone know what I can do about this?

Comment: Are you setting the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` of your labels? Just checking. :)

Comment: Yup. Just like in the tutorial. :-) in the end I used the boundingRectInSize... Method. Very hacky but it works. :-(